# Custom field in menu item

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, menu-item, custom-field, joomla-3.9

I am trying to get a custom field type into the menu. I want this to be a dropdown which I poulate with some php code.

[image]
Where the arrow points in want my dropdown field.

So I created in /components/com_hccxmlbeheer/models/fields/actiecode.php
with the following code:

```
// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla! defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldActiecodes extends JFormField {

    protected $type = 'Actiecodes';

    // getLabel() left out

    public function getInput() {
        return '<select id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'">'.
            '<option value="1" >New York</option>'.
            '<option value="2" >Chicago</option>'.
            '<option value="3" >San Francisco</option>'.
            '</select>';
    }
 }
```

in default.xml of component frontend, I added the field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <metadata>
    <layout title="COM_HCCXMLBEHEER_HCCXMLBEHEER_VIEW_AANMELDFORM_TITLE">
        <message>COM_HCCXMLBEHEER_HCCXMLBEHEER_VIEW_AANMELDFORM_DESC</message>
    </layout>
    <fields name="request">
        <fieldset name="request" addfieldpath="components/com_hccxmlbeheer/models/fields">
            <field
                    addfieldpath="/components/com_hccxmlbeheer/models/fields"
                    name="actiecode"
                    type="Actiecodes"
                    label="COM_HCCXMLBEHEER_HCCXMLBEHEER_ACTIECODELABEL"
                    description="COM_HCCXMLBEHEER_HCCXMLBEHEER_ACTIECODEDESC"
            >
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </fields> </metadata>
```

I see the field, but is not a dropdown and I can't select anything.

I also added to components/com_hccxmlbeheer/models/aanmeldformulier

```
JFormHelper::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT.'/models/fields');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: After many years of membership on Stackoverflow, thank you for coming to JSE. Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `actiecode.php` to `actiecodes.php`.

Class name, filename and field type in XML form must all match.

Comment: This was the solution, it was not clear in the documentation i found. i sugested an update. Thanks you verry mutch

Comment: Could you please provide the link to the document that was not clear enough? @Bas

Comment: Is there a relevant up to date document?